# HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync throws exception "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Upon receiving the request on the service side, I always retrieve the content by calling ReadAsStringAsync on the HttpContent object. From the service logs I can see that many times on line HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync, the service raises following exception

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Does anyone know why would I see this exception? and how to resolve this?

thx

Comment: Can you show us the entire method/action with only the relevant code?

Comment: Basically, I am extending the MediaTypeFormatter and in the class overriding the 
public virtual Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

The very first line is content.ReadAsStringAsync() where i see the above mentioned exception.

Comment: You should provide a simple but working example which you can edit into your question. I am missing the `await` operator in your comment: `await content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: Did you call `GetContext` or `GetContextAsync`?